# How to let users re-enter input in menu selection?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a menu that will let user try again until they enter a valid selection which is (1-5). If user enters something else, I want it to show a error message and keep letting them try again. Clearly my problem here is in my while loop, but I'm not sure how to solve this bug. Can someone help me to restructure this code, thank you.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void myList() {
    char selection;
    cout << "\n Select Equipments by category for more details";
    cout << "\n====================================================";
    cout << "\n 1 - Gardening Equipment";
    cout << "\n 2 - Building Equipment";
    cout << "\n 3 - Decorating Equipment";
    cout << "\n 4 - Car Maintenance Equipment";
    cout << "\n 5 - Miscellaneous";
    cout << "\n X - Exit";
    cout << "\n Enter selection: ";

    // read the input
    cin >> selection;
    while((selection != 1) || (selection != 2) || (selection != 3) ||
          (selection != 4) || (selection != 5)) {
        cout << "ERROR: Invalid Key - Try Again: ";
        cin >> selection;
        cout << endl;
        switch(selection)
        {
        case '1':
            system("CLS");
            cout << " [GARDENING EQUIPMENT]" << endl
                 << " 1.Hoe" << endl
                 << " 2.Spade" << endl
                 << " 3.Fork" << endl
                 << " 4.Shovel" << endl
                 << " 5.Rake" << endl
                 << " 6.Saw" << endl
                 << " 7.Wheelbarrow" << endl;
            break;
        case '2':
            system("CLS");
            cout << " [BUILDING EQUIPMENT]" << endl
                 << " 1.Rammer" << endl
                 << " 2.Crowbar" << endl
                 << " 3.Cordless Drill" << endl
                 << " 4.Safety Helmet" << endl
                 << " 5.Safety Glass" << endl
                 << " 6.Spirit Level" << endl
                 << " 7.Concrete Mixer" << endl;
            break;
        case '3':
            system("CLS");
            cout << " [DECORATING EQUIPMENT]" << endl
                 << " 1.Wallpaper Strippers" << endl
                 << " 2.Paint rollers" << endl
                 << " 3.Protective Sheets" << endl
                 << " 4.Paint Trays" << endl
                 << " 5.Step Ladder" << endl
                 << " 6.Paint Conditioner" << endl
                 << " 7.Stanley Knife" << endl;
            break;
        case '4':
            system("CLS");
            cout << " [CAR MAINTENANCE EQUIPMENT]" << endl
                 << " 1.Extension Bar" << endl
                 << " 2.Spark Plug Pilers" << endl
                 << " 3.Air Compressor" << endl
                 << " 4.Oil drain & caddy" << endl
                 << " 5.Engine Hoist" << endl
                 << " 6.Brake lathe" << endl
                 << " 7.Transmission Jack" << endl;
            break;
        case '5':
            system("CLS");
            cout << " [MISCELLANEOUS]" << endl
                 << " 1.Cleaning Powder" << endl
                 << " 2.Aluminium Foil" << endl
                 << " 3.Filter Paper" << endl
                 << " 4.Nylon Scrubber" << endl
                 << " 5.Floor Duster" << endl
                 << " 6.Dettol" << endl
                 << " 7.Disposable Garbage Bag" << endl;
            break;
        case 'X':
        case 'x': {
            cout << "\n To exit the menu";
        }
        break;
            // other than A, M, D and X...
        default:
            cout << "\n Invalid selection";
            // no break in the default case
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    myList();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"Clearly my problem here..."_ please describe your problem.

Comment: Why instructors always ask  to create text based menu systems? This requires a lot of acrobatics because of the non standard console definition. What is a text based menu teaching the students?

Comment: What is supposed to happen if the user enters 2 invalid selections in a row? You don't check the second `cin >> selection` right now.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana, clearly they've learned something today!

Comment: I think the general structure for this kind of thing should be: 1. prompt for an input 2. take input 3. check input and set valid/invalid flag 4. if invalid, optionally print an error and loop back to either 1 or 2. A `do{...}while(...);` loop may be best.

Comment: This is an example where spoken language doesn't match computer language.  In your mind you probably think "if it's not a 1 or a 2", and then write code `(x != 1) || (x != 2)`  But what you actually mean is "if it's not a 1 **and** it's not a 2": like this `(x != 1) && (x != 2)`  Many beginners even try to write `x != (1 || 2)` which gets you into even more trouble!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The condition `(selection != 1) || (selection != 2) || (selection != 3) || (selection != 4) || (selection != 5)` with `char selection;` will always be true because no integer is equal to 1 and 2 at the same time.

You should use `&&` (logical AND) instead of `||` (logical OR).

Also you may want to compare the input with *characters* like `'1'` instead of *integers* (character codes) like `1`.

In conclusion, the condition should be:

```
(selection != '1') && (selection != '2') && (selection != '3') && (selection != '4') && (selection != '5')
```

Or you may want simpler one:

```
selection < '1' || '5' < selection
```